# Exchange of integral and uniform convergence

Tags: uniform-convergence

I am trying to find a series expansion of

$\displaystyle f(x) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(x\cos{\theta})d\theta \tag*{}$

To do that, I tried to use the power series of $\cos{x}$. We have

$\displaystyle f(x) = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(x\cos{\theta})^{2n}}{(2n)!} d\theta \tag*{}$

Now, I would like to exchange summation and integral, but I don't know how to prove the uniform convergence of the summation.

My friend told me that it is uniformly convergent since the power series of cos has a radius of convergence $\infty$, but I don't know how to fill a gap to obtain uniform convergence.

Comment: You can use the Weierstrass M-test to prove uniform convergence of the series.

Comment: The first step in proving uniform convergence is understanding what it means as what your friend said is incorrect. What is uniform convergence in your own words? And what is the domain of $x$ ?

Comment: @NinadMunshi The domain of $x$ was some bounded set $K$. The definition of uniform convergence I know is $\sup_{x}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$

Comment: An old math professor of mine taught me to think of the meaning of the words, as the terms and definitions we use did not pop into existence - they were passed down because they were useful and connected ideas across certain fields. "Convergence" obviously means some sort of limit exists, but what purpose does the word "uniform" add? And why does it appear in other places like "uniform" continuity? The modifier of "uniformity" means that the rates of the limit (the epsilon bounds) are "uniform" i.e. there is no special location in $x$ which we need to treat differently.

Comment: If the domain of $x$ was bounded, what you want to show is that the normal notion of the limit existing holds (in this case $n>N$ there exists $\epsilon$, etc etc) *but* with the added condition that such a bound on the rate of convergence (the $\epsilon$) is "uniform" no matter the choice of $x$ to look at on the interval. Theorems like the Weierstrass M-test prove that bounding a series with an $x$ by an absolutely converging series without an $x$ proves you gain "uniformity" in convergence to your limit.

Comment: $f(x)$ is a quite well known function.